# efficient way to get key from std::map value

Tags: c++, performance, stdmap

I have a map as below :

```
std::map< std::string ,int> mapobj;
mapobj["one"] = 1;
mapobj["two"] = 2;
mapobj["three"] =3 ;
```

how to get key when input is value

EX :

**input   : 1**

**output  : one**

**Note : In my case value is unique**

Comment: std::map is not designed to do that efficiently, you may need something else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A one-to-one mapping is actually quite easy, the fastest way to do it is to probably maintain *two* maps, one for each direction. It becomes more complicated if it's not one-to-one since you'll need to provide a way to get a *collection* of values or key, rather than a single one. Happily, you only have the one-to-one requirement.

One of the maps is the one you have now, the other will map the values to a given key, soboth would be:

```
std::map<std::string, int> forwardmapobj;
std::map<int, std::string> reversemapobj;
```

and these would be maintained within a `bidimap` class of some sort.

Whenever you insert to, or delete from, your `bidimap`, you have to perform the equivalent operation on *both* internal maps.

For example, here's some pseudo-code. It maintains the two maps and ensures that they'e kept in sync for whatever operations you have that change the keys and values:

```
class biDiMap:
    map<string, int> forwardMap
    map<int, string> reverseMap

    void add(string key, int val):
        if exists forwardMap[key]: throw exception 'duplicate key'
        if exists reverseMap[val]: throw exception 'duplicate value'
        forwardMapObj[key] = val
        reverseMapObj[val] = key

    void delKey(string key):
        if not exists forwardMap[key]: throw exception 'no such key'
        delete reverseMap[forwardMap[key]]
        delete forwardMap[key]

    void delVal(int val):
        if not exists reverseMap[val]: throw exception 'no such value'
        delete forwardMap[reverseMap[val]]
        delete reverseMap[val]

    int getValFor(string key): return forwardMap[key]

    string getKeyFor(int val): return reverseMap[val]
```

Obviously, there's plenty of *other* stuff you could add but that should form the basis. In any case, you've probably got *enough* work ahead of you turning that into a C++ class :-)

---

If you *don't* want to roll your own solution, then Boost has a very good one that you can pretty well use as is. [`Boost.Bimap`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) provides a fully-templated bi-directional map that you should be able to use with minimal code, such as the following complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::exception;
using boost::bimap;

int main()
{
    typedef bimap<string, int> SiMap;
    typedef SiMap::value_type SiEntry;

    SiMap bidi;
    bidi.insert(SiEntry("ninety-nine", 99));
    int i = 0;
    for (string str: {"one", "two" , "three", "four", "five", "six"}) {
        bidi.insert(SiEntry(str, ++i));
    }

    cout << "The number of entries is " << bidi.size() << "\n\n";

    for (auto i = 1; i <= 7; i += 3) {
        try {
            cout << "Text for number " << i << " is " << bidi.right.at(i) << "\n";
        } catch (exception &e) {
            cout << "Got exception looking up number " << i << ": " << e.what() << "\n";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";

    for (auto str: {"five", "ninety-nine", "zero"}) {
        try {
            cout << "Number for text '" << str << "' is " << bidi.left.at(str) << "\n";
        } catch (exception &e) {
            cout << "Got exception looking up text '" << str << "': " << e.what() << "\n";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

It creates a bi-directional mapping between the textual form of a number and the integral value, then does a few lookups (in both directions) to show that it works:

```
The number of entries is 7

Text for number 1 is one
Text for number 4 is four
Got exception looking up number 7: bimap<>: invalid key

Number for text 'five' is 5
Number for text 'ninety-nine' is 99
Got exception looking up text 'zero': bimap<>: invalid key
```

Comment: hi i need your help. I have more then 300 key value pair which need to be mapped i am doing this mapping at init level. Is 300 key value addition is good or should i mantain a file where list of all the key and value will avaliable and i will use add method to inset in map. Can you please suggest best approach.

Comment: @Ysurf: whether it's best done entirely in code with hard-coded values, or read in from a file at some time, depends mostly on how often the data will change and who will change it. If the user of your code is never expected to change it and you don't mind a new release whenever it has to change, in the code is fine. If you want to change it without a new release, or if you want the user to be able to change it, a text file read at startup would be better.

Comment: Got it Thank you ;-)

Comment: @Ysurf: I've also given you a C++ solution using Boost's `bimap`, a bi-directional map which is probably going to be better than anything you (or I, for that matter) could do on our own :-)

Answer (score 6):

I do notice that this has the "stdmap" tag, so this may not be appropriate.  However [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) has `boost::bimap<>` which will allow you to do what you want: it allows lookup by either key or value.

Answer (score 2):

> how to get key when input is value

1. First, there is no guarantee that value is unique. I realize that you are saying it is unique. Still, conceptually speaking, this is something to keep in mind when looking at the problem.
2. Second, `std::map` is not sorted by value. Hence, the most efficient algorithm to look for a value will be `O(N)` on an average.

Comment: In my case value in unique. can you please help me with example code.

Comment: @Ysurf, Iterate over the items of the map and compare the values. I hope you are perfectly capable of that. If you are not sure how to do that, it's time to invest in [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn the language well.

Answer (score 0):

Try boost Bimap. all the things you are trying to do can simply be done by it.

1 --> one
2 --> two
...
one --> 1
two --> 2
...

here is a link where a working example is present.
[here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/bimap/example/simple_bimap.cpp)